# Convolution theorem for Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $(f*g)(t):=\int_0^t f(s) g(t-s)ds.$

Then the Laplace transform $L$ satisfies $L(f*g)(t)=L(f)(t)L(g)(t).$

This is known as the convolution theorem.

I would like to know whether something similar holds in this situation:

$$F(t):=\int_0^t \int_0^s f(t-s,s-k)u(s)u(k) dk ds.$$

This is still a one-dimensional object, but it looks somehow like a double convolution. Thus, can we say anything about the Laplace transform of this object?

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: The right-hand side is a function of $t$ and $s$.  The upper limit of integration in the inner integral is a free variable.  If by "one dimensional object" you mean a function of one variable, as I take it you do, then this statement is not correct.

Comment: @saulspatz no, the right hand side does not depend on $s$, you integrate over it

Comment: You can't integrate over the limit of integration.  The $s$ inside the integral sign is fine, you integrate it out.  But how can you say that the value of the integral doesn't depend on the limits of integration?

Comment: @saulspatz of course one can integrate over the limit of integration. If you have some doubts about the right hand side, please express them clearly. So far you claimed that it depends on t and s which is not true, as we integrate over s and that you cannt integrate over the limits of integration which is also not true. So what are you concerned about?

Comment: @Sascha Saul is basically saying $\int_{0}^{x} f(x) dx$ doesnt make sense.

Comment: @saulspatz, look closer.  If we rearrange the integral, we get $F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} u(s) \left(\int_{0}^{s} f(t - s, s - k) u(k) \, dk \right) \, ds,$, which is not a function of $s$ at all.  $s$ is a dummy variable being integrated over $[0,t]$; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @fourierwho Tell me, what is the value of $\int_0^s{ds}?$

Comment: @saulspatz this is not defined, but it appears nowhere in the above expression (look atr the comment above)

Comment: @Sascha I don't think it's fruitful to continue this discussion.